# How to add separative commas every 3 digits in solidity to an input integer?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, smart-contract-wallets

Is there a way to add separative commas to large input numbers? let's say the input was 1000, I want the output for this function to be a casted string that has this format "1,000".

Note: I'm using the Openzepplin unit to string library.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

function myNum(uint256 _Num) public pure returns(string memory){
        return (Strings.toString(_Num));
    }
```

Comment: You could parse the number and build your own string, adding a `,` every `x / 1000`. But isn't this something you'd want to do on the frontend with a library such as numeraljs?

Comment: The problem is I want this to function inside the smart contract, which means everything has to be on chain. The output will be displayed as an svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this at client level with a library such as [numeraljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeral). Even so, here's a way to do it directly in solidity. Note: there are probably more efficient or cleaner approaches.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

pragma solidity 0.8.11;

contract CommaFormatter {

    using Strings for uint256;
    function concat (string memory base, uint256 part, bool isSet) internal pure returns (string memory) {  
            string memory stringified = part.toString();
            string memory glue = ",";

            if(!isSet) glue = "";
            return string(abi.encodePacked(
                    stringified, 
                    glue, 
                    base));
    }

    function format (uint256 source) public pure returns (string memory) {   
        string memory result = "";
        uint128 index;

        while(source > 0) {
            uint256 part = source % 10; // get each digit
            bool isSet = index != 0 && index % 3 == 0; // if we're passed another set of 3 digits, request set glue

            result = concat(result, part, isSet);
            source = source / 10;
            index += 1;
        }
 
        return result;
    }

}
```